# Sticky Content JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I'm trying to rewrite the script jQuery for JS. Unfortunately, something went wrong and the script does not work.

Correct example in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/xHQyK/

My example in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/kzywiec/f0x6e1cd/

Please fix the code, or suggestions how to fix it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var boxLeft = $("#box").position().left;
  var containerHeight = $("#box").closest("#content").height();
  var containerOffset = $("#box").closest("#content").offset().top;
  var height = $("#box").outerHeight();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#box").each(function() {
      var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (windowScroll < containerOffset) {
        $(this).removeClass("fixed bottom");
      } else if (windowScroll > containerHeight + containerOffset - height) {
        $(this).removeClass("fixed").addClass("bottom").css({
          "left": ""
        });
      } else {
        var leftValue = boxLeft + $(this).closest("#content").offset().left;
        $(this).removeClass("bottom").addClass("fixed").css({
          "left": leftValue
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

My code in JS:

```js
function stickyContent() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box"), 
      boxLeft = box.offsetLeft;
  /*document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = boxLeft; //nieważne*/

  var containerHeight = document.getElementById("box").closest('div');
  containerHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(containerHeight).height);


  var rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  var containerOffset = rect.top;

  var height = document.getElementById("box").offsetHeight;

  window.onscroll = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll("box").forEach(function() {
      var windowScroll = window.onscroll.scrollTop();
      if (windowScroll < containerOffset) {
        this.classList.remove("fixed bottom");
      } else if (windowScroll > containerHeight + containerOffset - height) {
        this.classList.remove("fixed").classList.add("bottom").style.left = '';
      } else {
        var conten_value = document.getElementById("content").rect.top;
        var leftValue = boxLeft + this.conten_value.offsetLeft;
        this.classList.remove("bottom").classList.add("fixed").style.left = leftValue;
      }
    });
  }
}
window.onload=function() {
  stickyContent();
}
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: Arial;
 }
 
 #wrap {
   width: 800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 #header,
 #footer {
   height: 600px;
   background-color: #ccf;
 }
 
 #content {
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
 }
 
 #main {
   float: left;
   width: 610px;
 }
 
 #main p {
   margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
 }
 
 #aside {
   float: left;
   width: 190px;
 }
 
 #box {
   border: 2px solid red;
   width: 186px;
   background-color: #fcc;
   height: 200px;
   margin-top: 15px;
 }
 
 .fixed {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
 }
 
 .bottom {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 15px;
   right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="main">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 5amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue feugiat purus nec ornare. Morbi in diam sit amet erat iaculis gravida id sed mauris. Nunc vitae lacus varius risus elementum ultricies auctor nec eros. Vivamus vulputate
        quam risus, eget pharetra eros. Integer nec viverra nisi. Mauris pharetra velit nec nunc dignissim in pulvinar dui pellentesque. Donec volutpat malesuada odio, nec convallis tellus interdum eget. Pellentesque dictum varius vulputate. Nam quis
        auctor turpis. Donec consectetur lacus vitae arcu porta ut iaculis sem porttitor.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="aside">
      <div id="box" class="visible"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tell us your problem

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Both fiddles seem to work the same. Also note you can add snippets here by clicking the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: Your plain JS has function stickyContent() - where do you execute that? If I do `window.onload=function() {
  stickyContent();
}` I get console errors here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1t4radt2/

Comment: Here are some fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pf0hoyyh/ - you cannot use forEach on a single htmlelement

Comment: There are many errors in your code. `window.onscroll.scrollTop()` function is not defined.

Comment: Yea, this code better than my: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pf0hoyyh/
But it still does not work like the example that I gave.

Comment: I need this script only in pure js: https://codepen.io/jovanivezic/pen/ZQNdag